# Laravel http test redirecting to \ instead of login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Hi I am trying out testing in laravel 5.6 , but when try to test invalid login like below

```
public function testInvalidLogin()
    {
        $response = $this->post('/login',[ 'email'=>'fake@email.com', 'password'=>'secret' ]);
        $response->assertStatus(302);
        $response->assertLocation('/login');
    }
```

but when i run this i got error

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'http://localhost/login'
+'http://localhost'

D:\project\larademo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse.php:198
D:\project\larademo\tests\Feature\ExampleTest.php:38

FAILURES!
Tests: 3, Assertions: 5, Failures: 1.
```

I have also use `followingRedirects()` but it is giving response code 200 and content of '/'

can you help me what is wrong here

**EDIT** :  I expect it should redirect to login as when i use in browser after failed login it redirect back to login page, so test should redirect to login

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully, this answer will save several hours for someone, that **I lost** searching for information, of why this test fails...

Laravel, after failed login attempt, gets you redirected **back()** and NOT to */login* route. Found that in this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/8wc1na/laravel_http_test_redirecting_to_instead_of_login/

you can fix this by "simulating" user behavior and **starting from** */login* page (tested in Laravel 7.2.1):

```
public function test_user_is_redirected_back_to_login_page_after_failed_login()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $response = $this->get('/login');
    $response->assertStatus(200);

    $response = $this->post('/login', ['email' => $user->email, 'password' => 'wrong_pass']);
    $response->assertStatus(302);

    $response->assertRedirect('/login');
    $response->assertLocation('/login');
}
```

while researching, i stumbled upon Laravel Dusk. In my opinion, it is overkill to study dusk, if you just started learning Laravel testing. But, probably, good idea to at least get familiar with it at some point...

Comment: Thanks! in 2024 in L10 I have to use: $user = User::factory()->createOne(['email'=>.....

Answer (score 1):

`assertLocation` [checks the `Location` header](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#assert-location), which **will** be set to `/` because that's where the redirect is pointing to.

Comment: but i expect it returns to login after fail, in browser it returns to login page , so should be in test , is there anything i am missing ?

Comment: Does `/` redirect to `login` if you're not logged in? i.e. does it go `login -> / -> login`?

Comment: `/` is home page and it wont redirect automatically to login ,

Comment: Well, your code is issuing a redirect to the home page if the user fails validation. Can you share the code for the `login` route?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you probably used return back on invalid login, where the test case back is pointed to the '/' URL so it will be redirected to that page. In order to overcome this, you can use @arty marty solution or you could append a from route to your post request like this:

```
public function testInvalidLogin()
{
    $response = $this->from('/login')
                     ->post('/login',[ 
                           'email'=>'fake@email.com', 
                           'password'=>'secret' 
                     ]);
    $response->assertStatus(302);
    $response->assertLocation('/login');
}
```